# Maxima keyboard input from batch

Tags: batch-file, user-input, maxima

If I copy and paste in wxMaxima these lines

```
assume(omega>0);
damp_vib:'diff(x,t,2)+2*'xi*'omega*'diff(x,t)+'omega^2*x=0;
ode2(damp_vib,x,t);
negative;
```

the last line correctly answers to Maxima asking if a parameter is negative, zero, or positive (the solution depends on that).

But if I put the same lines in a text file and run it using the `batch` command, the last line is not taken as answer and I have to enter it manually from keyboard. How can this be avoided?

Comment: So other know about `maxima`: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/  Also http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_4.html#SEC7 for command line help.

Comment: Maxima is amazing, unfortunately I know much less than I'd like to.

Comment: When you say that you place the lines in a text file and run it as a batch file, do you mean a literal .bat file or by using the `load` option in maxima?

Comment: The `batch("my_commands.txt")` command. Unfortunately `batch()` explicitly waits for user input when needed, differently from the behaviour of wxMaxima when pasting text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to get Maxima to read the 'asksign' response from the file. I think the best way to resolve this problem is to put `assume(xi^2 < 1)` (or whatever it should be) before the function call which triggers 'asksign'.

Comment: I tried that way but it seems that Maxima ignores some assumptions. Maxima exactly asks `Is  "(xi-1)*(xi+1)"  positive, negative, or zero?`. I tried `assume(xi^2<1)`, `assume(xi^2-1<0)`, `assume((xi-1)*(xi+1)<0)`, and others, but Maxima keeps asking something (slightly different and strangely more than once). By the way, thanks for your "Minimal Maxima", Robert, my 1st Maxima manual.